# Maintaining a set number of concurrent jobs w/ args from a file in bash

Tags: bash

I found this script on the net, I don't know to work in bash too much is too weird but..

Here's my script:

```
CONTOR=0
for i in `cat targets`
do
CONTOR=`ps aux | grep -c php`

while [ $CONTOR -ge 250 ];do
CONTOR=`ps aux | grep -c php`
sleep 0.1
done

if [ $CONTOR -le 250 ]; then
php b $i > /dev/null &
fi

done
```

My targets are urls, and the b php file is a crawler which save some links into a file. The problem is max numbers of threads is 50-60 and that's because the crawler finish very fast and that bash script code doesn't have time to open my all 250 threads. It's any chance to do something to open all threads (250) ? It is possible to run more than one thread per ps -aux process? Right know seems he open 1 thread after execute ps -aux.

Comment: Optimizations are certainly possible even within the current framework. For instance, why check `ps` at all until after you've started at least 250 jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Bash has no multithreading support whatsoever. `foo &` starts a separate process, not a thread.

Second: launching `ps` to check for children is both prone to false positives (treating unrelated invocations of `php` as if they were jobs in the current process) and extremely inefficient if done in a loop (since every invocation involves a fork()/exec()/wait() cycle).

---

Thus, don't do it that way: Use a release of GNU xargs with `-P`, or (if you must) GNU parallel.

Assuming your `targets` file is newline-delimited, and has no special quoting or characters, this could be as simple as:

```
xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 -P 250 php b <targets
```

...or, for pure POSIX shells:

```
xargs -d "
" -n 1 -P 250 php b <targets
```

Comment: fwiw, `pgrep -c php` would be more reliable and a bit less inefficient than the `ps | grep` combo. But xargs/parallel is better.

Comment: Efficiency isn't the issue, as much as what happens if someone _else_ is running php....

Comment: Be aware that the `-d $'\n'` construct does not work in every shell (e.g. csh, ash, sash, dash, and sh). (GNU Parallel would work though :-)

Comment: @OleTange, ...strictly syntax sugar; one could type `"`, <carriage-return>, `"` and have the same effect in any POSIX-compliant shell. And a system which doesn't have bash available (even if non-default) isn't likely to have GNU parallel installed either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy just for completeness: It still would not work in neither tcsh nor csh (which seems to be the default shell in e.g. NetBSD 6.1.3).

Comment: @OleTange, no csh-family shell is compliant with POSIX sh, to which I confined my assertion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ... which is why I mention it for completeness: If you are a user with the default shell being csh on, say, NetBSD 6.1.3, then your solution does not work. But there _are_ solutions that would work under both csh and POSIX shells. Even one that is listed on this page :-)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this (choose the style you like best):

```
cat targets | parallel -P 250 php b
parallel -a targets -P 250 php b
parallel -P 250 php b :::: targets
```

There is no risk of false positives if there are other `php` processes running. And unlike `xargs` there is no risk if the file `targets` contain space, " or '.

Comment: `xargs` doesn't have that risk either, if used with `-0` (and appropriately formatted inputs -- which is appropriate, if we're trying to be pedantically correct, since UNIX filenames can contain newlines) or `-d $'\n'`. Granted, GNU extensions are required, but... well, `parallel` isn't even an extension but a whole new program.

Comment: "xargs doesn't have that risk either, if used with -0" My point exactly: You need to take extra care every single time you use xargs. Not so with GNU Parallel. Only if you have malicious users that put \n in file names (something I have yet to see normal users do in my 15+ years as sysadmin) will you have to use -0. Space, ' and ", however, are often used by normal users.

Comment: Not just malicious. The case of dataloss caused by a bad filename I've seen in my personal experience was a buffer overflow putting random junk into a name.

Comment: That said -- my real beef with GNU parallel is with regard to its implementation; it's a huge, unreadable mess of perl -- "no obvious bugs", as opposed to "obviously no bugs". I have a great deal of trouble trusting it.

Comment: I've taken the objection to heart, though, and added `-d $'\n'` to the xargs line given in my answer.